Angular 'Signal' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.ts(2693)
I'm using angular version 17.2.0. And in the service
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Signal, ReadOnlySignal } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root' // Make the service available throughout the application
})
export class CurrentTimeService {
  private currentTimeInSeconds = new Signal<number>(); // throw Error in this line.
}
}

I want to create a service in the latest angular version 17.2.0 for getting currentTime based on in Angular signal

As the error says, we need to define the signal with a small first letter signal instead of Signal(type). Also we don't need to use new!
Angular signal documentation
Signal tutorial
import { Injectable, signal } from '@angular/core';
import { Signal } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class CurrentTimeService {
  private currentTimeInSeconds = signal<number>(0);

  constructor() {}
}


The reason you are getting that error, is because Signal (uppercase S) is a type, as seen by the first word here:
type Signal<T> = (() => T) & {
  [SIGNAL]: unknown;
}

Whereas signal (lowercase s) is a function as seen by the first word here:
function signal<T>(initialValue: T, options?: CreateSignalOptions<T>): WritableSignal<T>

That being said, when trying to instantiate or execute a type, you get that error due to the fact that when compiled, nothing exists as the type is removed.
This then means that the correct syntax would look like this:
import { signal } from '@angular/core';

private currentTimeInSeconds = signal(0);

